# Neo4J: How to correctly match key-value-pairs in Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a question regarding my Cypther query. I want to attach certain values as properties to nodes with a certain id, which is also a proerty.
So for the purposes of a small reproducible example let's say we have 3 `nodes` called `car`. Each of these nodes has the property `id`. Now for two `nodes` I have the value `max_speed` and these nodes I want to identify via the `id`and attach the `max_speed`. Therefore I have two lists `id = [1, 2]` and `max_speed = [180, 200]`. And with this lists I want to update two of the three `car` nodes. So the node with the `id = 1`should get the the `max_speed = 180` etc.

I guess my Cypher should look something like this, but unfortunately I don't know how to write the `SET` statement and would really appreciate your help.

```
MATCH (c:car)
WHERE ANY (id IN c.id WHERE id IN [1, 2])
SET ...
RETURN c
```

Thank you very much in advance and have a nice weekend.

M.

Comment: Can you clarify a little bit? You have n nodes, n `id` values and n `val` values and you'd like for the first node to have a label `id1` and `val1`, the second node `id2` and `val2`. Is that correct? How do you define the order on your nodes?
Are you sure you want use n **label** values? Labels are supposed to group similar nodes, not distinguish them.

Comment: @fbiville first of all thank you very much for your comment. As I am new to neo4J I hope you do not mix up the terminology. 
I have ` ` `n` ` ` nodes, e.g. 50. This nodes have the property / label "id". Beside of that i have two lists with e.g. 40 ` ` `ids` ` ` and the corresponding 40 ```values```.
Whenever I have a match between my an ```id``` from the database and my list, i want to attach another label / property called ```value``` with the value corresponding value of my second list. 
If there is the possibility to use something like a  ```python dict```   I would be happy to use it.

Comment: @fbiville I updated the question and provided a little example in order to clearify what I want to achive. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

[UNWIND](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/4.2/clauses/unwind/#unwind-creating-nodes-from-a-list-parameter) is one way to do it.
I used browser params to demo the concept to you:

`:param carspeeds => ({cars:[{ id:1, speed:10},{ id:2, speed:20}]})`

```
UNWIND $carspeeds.cars AS carspeed
MATCH (c:Car {id:carspeed.id})
SET c.maxSpeed=carspeed.speed
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just one additional question. Will the carspeeds variable with the corresponding values be stored persistently (somewhere in the db) or can I just access it in this special Cyper query (which is what I kind of assume).

Comment: No, these are parameters that you will supply to your query using whichever Neo4j client/driver. See https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/syntax/parameters/#cypher-parameters-introduction